# reference DTS.Variables in other classes in SSIS script task

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package which has a script task.  It has of course the usual Script main  class file, it uses a couple of web services so I used the  WSDL command line too to generate a couple of proxy classes for those in the project.  All works fine.

I defined a couple of read-only User:: variables to be used by the script task which define the URL paths of the two web services.

Problem : in the two web service proxy classes I seem not to have access to the Dts variables collection.  I've tried adding the using `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;`  to each of the proxy classes but still cannot access those Dts variables within the proxy classes.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to pass the variables to a class constructor by passing the ScriptObjectModel.

```
// in the ScriptMain class
YourWsClass ws = new YourWsClass(Dts);

//in the WS class
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask;

class YourWsClass
{
    public YourWsClass(ScriptObjectModel dts)
    {
       string _v = (string)dts.Variables["User::YourVariable"].Value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to access the variables directly anywhere else than in the `ScriptMain` class. You have to pass the variable to your proxy class when you instantiate it.

```
// in the ScriptMain class
YourWsClass ws = new YourWsClass(Dts.Variables["User::YourVariable"].Value.ToString();

class YourWsClass
{
    public YourWsClass(String v)
    {
        _v = v;
    }
}
```